# How do I ensure consistency between MemCache and Datastore on GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am writing multiple entites to the datastore using a transaction. I want to keep these entities in MemCache, also. How do I ensure that the copy of the entity in MemCache actually equals the copy in Datastore?

E.g. I can do:

```
tx.begin()
datastore.put(entity)
if (memcache.putIfUntoched(key, entity))
  tx.commit()
```

But then if the transaction fails the entity will possibly end up in the MemCache but not in the Datastore. On the other hand, if I do:

```
tx.begin()
datastore.put(entity)
tx.commit()
memcache.putIfUntoched(key, entity))
```

then the Datastore transaction might succeed but the MemCache update could fail. How can I ensure consistency?

Comment: I think, if you use NDB, NDB will take care.

Comment: My application is Java :-( How is NDB doing it?

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand you use Java. NDB is a project of the master: Guido van Rossum. By the way. In Python I have never seen memcache updates fail. Memcache set does not have any exceptions or return codes. But you can detect problems with the capabilities API. And I found this: http://osdir.com/ml/GoogleAppEngine/2009-10/msg00437.html

Comment: memcache.put() will most probably never fail but putIfUntouched() will fail on concurrent updates.

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, it may not be that helpful if you write to the DB and the cache at the same time. In general, mixing DB transactions with other stuffs (e.g. file system) is difficult to do it right.

I suggest you change your program logic, so that

1. When you create a new record, write only to DB
2. When you update an existing record, write to DB, and invalidate corresponding slots in cache
3. When you're looking for a record, just check the cache. If it's not there, load from DB and fill in  the cache

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. You solution would be easy to implement, but it smells like a workaround. For entities that are used frequently but update rarely a cache invalidation strategy is ok, however I have some entities that update frequently (e.g. resource counters) and I was hoping to take their previous value from MemCache and eliminate the datastore read.

Comment: Ohh one more thing: If you evict the cache, how can you make sure that the removal operation is in synch with the datastore? E.g. when another request concurrently fetches the object from memcache after you commited but before you evicted, don't you run into the same problem?

Comment: @Michael As long as what the other request sees are consistent, it's ok, just like MVCC for DB transactions. So you can also specify a timeout instead of explicitly invalidating the cached item.

Comment: @Michael a cache is not transactional, so there is no support for consistency like on relational database have. and its not needed, the logic solutions from Xiao is quite usual. and if it happens that at the nearly same time a read and write/delete request comes, it does not matter what the reader gets (date before or after write... ), because its a web application he can do the request again. but if transactions are importend then dont use a cache, use a relational db, create a ER schema that fits your performance needs and run it in cluster.

Comment: @Michael and as hint for GAE, check you cache hitrate for this entity. if its less then 50%, its better to change to optimized database entity and dont use cache, because each write and read from cache also cost GAE time.

Comment: @XiaoJia what to do if two instances work concurrently, and one performs update + memcache invalidation, while other performs fetch and cache put?
- If you update memcache after DB transaction, the cache put may be perfomed after invalidate (althout DB read was done before DB update).
- If you update cache within transaction, you perform cache put before you check if DB read was successful (it can still be aborted and retried, right?)